# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' [Python3.7 using code from python2]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run this py file.

```
writer.writerow([0]+[PrivacyAgent.get_m(r) for r in range(len(Delta_accountant)-1)])

with open(save_dir + '/specs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        if FLAGS.priv_agent == True:
            writer.writerow([0]+[PrivacyAgent.get_m(r) for r in range(len(Delta_accountant)-1)])
        if FLAGS.priv_agent == False:
            writer.writerow([0]+[FLAGS.m]*(len(Delta_accountant)-1))
        writer.writerow(Delta_accountant)
        writer.writerow(Accuracy_accountant)
```

and get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "sample.py", line 90, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "sample.py", line 36, in main
    sample(N=FLAGS.N, b=FLAGS.b, e=FLAGS.e,m=FLAGS.m, sigma=FLAGS.sigma, eps=FLAGS.eps, save_dir=FLAGS.save_dir, log_dir=FLAGS.log_dir)
  File "sample.py", line 33, in sample
    save_dir=save_dir, log_dir=log_dir)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning-main_v2/DiffPrivate_FedLearning.py", line 192, in run_differentially_private_federated_averaging
    accuracy_accountant + [float('nan')], privacy_agent, FLAGS)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning-main_v2/Helper_Functions.py", line 279, in save_progress
    writer.writerow([0]+[PrivacyAgent.get_m(r) for r in range(len(Delta_accountant)-1)])

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I've seen couple of examples saying that using `.encode()` or add `b` could help, but i don't really know where to put, could anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a self-contained [mre] of your code. This likely has to do with the code contained in `PrivacyAgent.get_m()`. Please also post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, after I changed the code to `PrivacyAgent.decode(UTF-8).get_m(r)`, it's still not working and generated a new error of `AttributeError: 'PrivAgent' object has no attribute 'decode'"`

Comment: The `csv` module has a different `open` requirement between 2.x and 3.x.  Use `with open(save_dir + '/specs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:` then it will accept `str` instead of `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
with open(save_dir + '/specs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
#                              this ^^
```

You are opening your output file in binary mode, so your CSV `writer` object is going to complain when it receives text. Since text mode is the default mode of `open()`, just change that line to:

```
with open(save_dir + '/specs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

and you should be all set.